# Can I use Shibboleth to present different attributes of other users to different users

Tags: permissions, attributes, saml, shibboleth

OK, so it's a badly phrased question. But it's hard to explain in a single line.

I've tried to read the Shibboleth documentation and being a newbie got out of my depth fairly rapidly. I don't really want to spend days understanding it if an expert can take half a minute to say "no chance, that won't work".

I have many groups of users, lets say (for now) that groups are different companies.

What I'd like to do is only allow users to see some fields from other companies.

For example I'm Alice in Company A and I can see that Bob in Company B has an email address bob@b.com. He can see that I'm alice@a.com

However everyone else in Company B can see that Bob has a last name and a phone number etc.
And everyone else in Company A can see my details.

To make this more complicated, lets say that Bob and I become friends and decide we want to share our information then we create a "transient" group "alice&bob". Because we are both members of that group, we can both see each others full details. (But nobody else in A can see Bob's details unless they are also friends and vice versa)

I can sort all that out in application code by querying all attributes and relationships and only showing what's relevant but for extra security I'd like to limit the disclosure of information at source.

I think I need to use attribute filters but not sure if they are able to give me this level of control. With this flexibility of being able to form relationships, will I need to build filter files on the fly and then end up with thousands of filters that Shibboleth starts to choke on because the logic is so long.
Something like the "is requester in group" filter rule :
https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPFilterRequirementAttributeRequesterInEntityGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above is quite good, but i believe that non shibboleth users will find it confusing.

The quick answer is **You really don't want to do it this way, it may be possible to do but for 100% there are better tools to do it.**

Ok, full version now (sorry for being too obvious i some places).
In shibboleth architecture we can distinguish two main components.

Identity Provider **IdP**- which holds information about users from specific organizations.

Service Provider **SP** - which are generally some service or protected resource, for which we can define some access rules

In your example credentials for Alice and Bob could be stored in different IdP, because they are member of different organizations/companies, or (which isn't exactly matching the whole pattern) you can have one IdP for all users, and "company" is just one of user attributes. IdP doesn't provide you any kind of api that will give you opportunity to access users attributes for any user, apart from the one that is being authenticated.

On the other hand you have your SP, which hold some super secret resources, for which you can define policies. And in which you would like to define polices for user information.

And here lays the problem, on SP side you don't have access to whole users database, that's the way Shibboleth works. You can of course treat all users information as a resource in your SP, but why in the hell would you like to use Shibboleth if you have clear access to all users credentials on you application side?

If you store all users information on you service side I believe that any well designed relational database with some kind of authentication for your service will be better than shibboleth for this job.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a job for Shibboleth or for most SAML/SSO providers, for that matter.  The attribute filtering you speak of is used for filtering those attributes between the IdP and SP ... which is basically saying :  let service provider or "application" B see the following attributes from IdP A.

Once you transmit the attributes to the SP on the other end, Shibboleth does not (and indeed cannot) provide you with a mechanism to prevent users of application B from seeing any data that you present to them ... in fact, they really shouldnt be able to see any data transmitted by the IdP unless you are exposing it in someway via your application.